# How to move relatively to the angle?

Tags: c++, math, opengl, rotation, sdl

I keep looking up on the internet how to move from point A to point B on an angle with a specified distance. When I tried to code it, however, the camera just gets messed up and I'm moving in random directions. I am using SDL/OpenGL with c++ and this is my player function. Right now, I'm trying to get the player to move forwards along the angle.

```
void player_action()
{

    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                {
                    player.rotxl = (screen->w)/2;
                    player.rotxd = event.motion.x - player.rotxl;
                    player.rotx = player.rotx + (player.rotxd/4);
                    if (player.rotx < 0)
                    {
                        player.rotx = player.rotx + 360;
                    };
                    if (player.rotx > 360)
                    {
                        player.rotx = player.rotx - 360;
                    }
                };
            break;

            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_w:
                        {player.zvel = 8.0f;}; break;
                    case SDLK_a:
                        {player.xvel = 8.0f;}; break;
                    case SDLK_s:
                        {player.zvel = -8.0f;}; break;
                    case SDLK_d:
                        {player.xvel = -8.0f;}; break;
                    case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                        {running = false;}; break;
                    default: break;

                }; break;

            case SDL_KEYUP:
                switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_w:
                        {player.zvel = 0.0f;}; break;
                    case SDLK_a:
                        {player.xvel = 0.0f;}; break;
                    case SDLK_s:
                        {player.zvel = 0.0f;}; break;
                    case SDLK_d:
                        {player.xvel = 0.0f;}; break;
                    default: break;
                };
            break;
        };

    };

    player.x = player.x + float(player.zvel*cos((double)player.rotx));
    player.z = player.z + float(player.zvel*sin((double)player.rotx));

    glRotatef(player.rotx, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTranslatef(player.x, player.y, player.z);

    SDL_WarpMouse((screen->w/2), (screen->h/2));
};
```

Comment: You probably want a glPush() and glPop() around your glRotatef and glTranslatef so that your transforms don't keep building up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correct the math functions `sin` and `cos` both take angles in radians, **not** degrees as `player.rotx` seems to be. Try the following:

```
player.x = player.x + float(player.zvel*cos((double)player.rotx*0.0174532925));
player.z = player.z + float(player.zvel*sin((double)player.rotx*0.0174532925));
```

We're multiplying `player.rotx` by `pi/180`, which is how we convert degrees to radians.

Not sure if this is your only problem, but it certainly appears to be one of them.

Comment: +1, you just fixed my problem. I had no idea that was the case.

Comment: It's an easy thing to miss (in fact I did the same when I first implemented a similar mechanism in one of my own games a few years back). Glad you got it working :)

Comment: I should point out that after "fixing" the problem, the camera would always go to the left or right if I pressed the W or A keys. So, in glRotate3f, I changed the first argument to player.rotx + 90, and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible sources of the issue I see:

1. The standard C++ [cos/sin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/cos/) function take a function in radians instead of degrees (one radian = 180/pi degrees).
2. While I'm not familiar with SDL a quick look at the [docs](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlmousemotionevent.html) makes me think you should be using `event.motion.xrel` instead of `.x`. You'll have to change your rotx calculation which should not need the screen width.

Comment: For no. 2, I believe the OP calculates `xrel` manually here: `event.motion.x - player.rotxl`, using `SDL_WarpMouse((screen->w/2), (screen->h/2));` to keep the mouse centered continually so this works. But indeed it would probably be simpler to use `event.motion.xrel` compared to this method